# how do I use nitrogen in gnome?

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

whenever I try to put a wallpaper using nitrogen I get the following error;

```
(nitrogen:133201): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 20:36:16.526: Settings schema 'org.gnome.desktop.background' does not contain a key named 'draw-background Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)'
```

how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

[Nitrogen](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/nitrogen) is a GTK2 application for changing wallpapers on X11. Ubuntu uses GTK3 -going to GTK4-, GnomeShell (and even wayland)- so that ancient software can't be used for this type of desktop.

It might be supported on the Mate or XFCE desktops.

Comment: I am using manjaro xfce, how do I fix this next error; `Property "/backdrop/screen0/monitor0/workspace0/last-image" does not exist on channel "xfce4-desktop". If a new property should be created, use the --create option`

Comment: @thelinuxguide Manjaro is off-topic here.

Comment: @thelinuxguide - as ChanganAuto correctly points out - this is the wrong forum. Not that we don't like you here, but you'll get qualified help at [manjaro](http://forum.manjaro.org/) 
The forum is - like this one - friendly and helpful. ;-)